How to justify two columns in the altacv.cls environment?
I'm making a cv using altacv.cls (More Info). It uses the paracol environment to create two columns for each of the sections of the resume. However, no matter what I try to change (whether in the main tex document or the .cls file), the two columns seem to be left aligned rather than justified. When I use \justify, the spacing for each cv event or cv tag is messed up while the bullet points are justified. How do I ensure that the text is justified for all the bullet points without ruining the spacing for the cv event/ cv tag?
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}
%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome5 and packages.
%% See http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontawesome5 for full list of symbols.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.55cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,columnsep=1.5cm}

% The paracol package lets you typeset columns of text in parallel
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

\renewcommand{\namefont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\Large\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvItemMarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\cvRatingMarker}{\faCircle}

\begin{document}

\name{SOME NAME}
\tagline{SOME TAG}

\personalinfo{%
  \email{ABC@email.com}
  \email{ABC@email.com}
  \phone{00-000-0000}
  \location{ANYWHERE}
  \linkedin{www.linkedin.com/SOMENAME}
}
\makecvheader

\columnratio{0.55}
% Start a 2-column paracol. Both the left and right columns will automatically
% break across pages if things get too long.
\begin{paracol}{2}

\cvsection{Experience}

\cvevent{\textbf{EXPERIENCE 1}}{COMPANY 1}{MONTH -- Present}{LOCATION}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}

\cvevent{\textbf{EXPERIENCE 2}}{COMPANY 2}{MMYY -- MMYY}{LOCATION}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}

\cvevent{\textbf{EXPERIENCE 3}}{COMPANY 3}{MMYY -- MMYY}{LOCATION}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\switchcolumn
\cvsection{Education}

\cvevent{\textbf{DEGREE}}{COLLEGE}{CLASS OF X }{LOCATION}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{itemize}
\smallskip

\cvevent{\textbf{DEGREE 2 }}{COLLEGE 2}{CLASS OF X }{LOCATION}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[6]
\end{itemize}
\smallskip

\cvsection{Skills}

\cvtag{Skill}
\cvtag{Very Long Skill Title}
\cvtag{Mediumskill}
\cvtag{Skill}
\cvtag{Very Long Skill Title}
\cvtag{Mediumskill}
\cvtag{Skill That Is Also Long}
\cvtag{Skill}
\cvtag{Very Long Skill Title}
\cvtag{Mediumskill}
\smallskip

\cvsection{Certified Courses}
\cvtag{\textbf{Organization 1}} \smallskip

\begin{itemize}
    \item Course 1 With A Very Very Long Title, Hard To Fit Here correctly
    \item Course 2
    \item Course 3, Pretty Short
\end{itemize}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}


Use \justifying instead (analogous to \centering for centered content) from ragged2e - loaded as part of your class options. Also add a group to limit it to the itemized elements only:
%...
\cvevent{\textbf{EXPERIENCE 1}}{COMPANY 1}{MONTH -- Present}{LOCATION}
\begingroup\justifying
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\endgroup
%...


\justify actually sets a (new) list with \justifying, and therefore is a bit more complex for what you need.

Thank you! Do you also know how to make 'Location' align with the justified column? I went to the cvevent section of the altacv.cls but couldnt figure out where the alignment/spacing was mentioned.

@KN202: What do you mean by "align with the justified column?" You want the location to be flush-right rather than the current middle-ish placement?

yes that's exactly what I meant, sorry if it wasnt phrased well!

@KN202: Add \patchcmd{\cvevent}{\cvLocationMarker}{\hfill\cvLocationMarker}{}{} somewhere in your preamble. This patches \cvevent, inserting \hfill before the \cvLocationMarker, thereby making it flush-right with the margin. Both the date and location is set within a box half the width of the column (and left aligned). So, \hfill just pushes it to the right.
